# How I can access the Google project [. Net] through My visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http

On some Google project I read this

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://***.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ***-read-only
```

But  I never found how I can read their code. Any way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (or [TortoiseSvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/)) installed? If so, just run that command to check out the code to your local disk, then open the solution (or whatever) in Visual Studio.

Alternatively, check out the Downloads tab in their Google Code page. There may be a source zip file you can download directly.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions and check out the code via [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

Or you can browse it online if they have the Source -> Browse menu option enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Install a SVN client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). Once done, open the command prompt and type the above command.

Answer (score 1):

Few years back, I had used a commercial plugin that enabled SVN functionality within the VS for VS 2008. You can use that too in addition to the svn clients.